# HTML Table Static Header and Footer, Fixed height, No Resizing on TR

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a table in HTML that requires a fixed height. It has Static headers and footers.

The table is in a div that has a set height and is scrollable. My table height is set at 100%.

The issue that I am running into is that my TR and TD stretch to fill the space in the table body. I have tried setting a fixed height on the TR and TD, but they still stretch to fill the void.

How do I get around the TR and TD stretching to fill the content of the table body?

I am trying to achieve this strictly with CSS.

My Html and CSS

```
<div class="table-container">
    <table class="table-data-entry">
        <thead>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

.table-container {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    margin:0px 5px;
    height:500px;
}

.table-data-entry {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}

.table-data-entry th {
    z-index:100;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;        
    background-color: white;                
}

.table-data-entry tfoot {
    z-index: 100;
    position:sticky;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:0px
}
```

Comment: Could you update your question with your code, it will be more simple to help you, thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Lety Question has been updated with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix the height of the rows and add an empty row to fill the space.

I changed the `th` rule by assigning it to `thead`, just change the height and added the border to better see the behavior.

Here is the example with two table one with many rows and the other with one row:

```css
.table-container {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    margin:0px 5px;
    height:200px;
    border: 2px green solid;
}

.table-data-entry {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: 100%;
}
.table-data-entry td {
    border: 1px red solid;
}

.table-data-entry thead {
    z-index:100;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;        
    background-color: white;                
}

.table-data-entry tfoot {
    z-index: 100;
    position:sticky;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:0px;
}
.table-data-entry tr td {
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.table-data-entry tr.empty td {
    border: none;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
    <table class="table-data-entry">
        <thead>
                <td>Table</td>
                <td>with</td>
                <td>many</td>
                <td>rows</td>
                <td>test</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="empty">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="table-container">
    <table class="table-data-entry">
        <thead>
                <td>Table</td>
                <td>with</td>
                <td>one</td>
                <td>row</td>
                <td>test</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="empty">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
                <td>foot</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

As described in [css](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#height-layout) specification:

> The height of a table is given by the 'height' property for the
> 'table' or 'inline-table' element. A value of 'auto' means that the
> height is the sum of the row heights plus any cell spacing or borders.
> Any other value is treated as a minimum height. CSS 2.2 does not
> define how extra space is distributed when the 'height' property
> causes the table to be taller than it otherwise would be.
>
> Note. Future updates of CSS may specify this further.